# Dynamically generate @ServiceHost directive / Dynamic SVC files

Tags: wcf, iis, iis-7.5, castle-windsor, httpmodule

I am using Castle Windsor's WCF facility to host my services.
This means that my .svc files only contain this one line:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Service="MyService" Factory="Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.DefaultServiceHostFactory, Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration"%>
```

Now instead of having 10 .svc files for 10 services, I thought it would be nice to have just one generic file.

Something like `Generic.svc?service=MyService` that would automatically generate the correct `@ServiceHost` directive, maybe with URL rewriting in addition, so that I could write `MyService.svc`, but it would get rewritten to `Generic.svc`.

Any thoughts on this?
I don't want to move away from IIS and host the services myself.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for something like [this](http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=95)?

Comment: No. My architecture is fine, I'm not looking for something to replace Windsor.

Comment: The article doesn't tell you to replace Windsor. You can use Windsor with this model (although you can't use decorators with Windsor, but you can use interceptors).

Comment: You mean I wouldn't be able to use decorators with that model combined with Windsor? Because Windsor does support decorators.